# How to find the built-in function to deal with char16_t in C?

Tags: c, unicode, printf, char16-t

Please tell what is the `char16_t` version for the String Manipulation Functions

such as:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_function_references.htm

I found many references site, but no one mentioned that.

Especially for printing function, this is that most important, because it help me to verify whether the Manipulation function is work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <uchar.h>



char16_t *u=u"α";
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%x\n",u[0]); // output 3b1, it is UTF16



    wprintf("%s\n",u); //no ouput
    _cwprintf("%s\n",u); //incorrect output

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The incorrect output case may be because the terminal does not use the right encoding. Try forwarding output to file and look at its hex dump.

Comment: @CL So What is the "incorrect output"?

Comment: @hyde, @chux, I don't know how to print the UNICODE text to file, I try this `code FILE *f=fopen(L"e:\\test.txt",L"w");//and _wfopen
  int i=fwprintf(f,L"abc\n");
  printf("%d",i);
  fclose(f);`, the value of i is 3, and hex of test.txt is "61 62 0D 0A", correct UTF16-LE should be "61 00 62 00 0D 00 0A 00". For the incorrect output, I tried many combination, please this [link](home.netvigator.com/~fhappy/unicode_printf_result.7z), and please see the first screen, you can see the "α" is shown at my windows 7 console, it proof that my console is able to display the UNICODE character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wprintf` and its wchar colleagues need to have th format string in wchar too:
`wprintf( L"%s\n", u);`

For wchar **L** is used as a prefix to the string literals.

**Edit:**

Here's a code snippet (tested on Windows):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <wchar.h>

void main()
{
    wchar_t* a = L"α";
    fflush(stdout); //must be done before _setmode
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT); // set console mode to unicode
    wprintf(L"alpha is:\n\t%s\n", a);      // works for me :)
}
```

The console doesn't work in unicode and prints a "?" for non ascii chars. In Linux you need to remove the underscore prefix before `setmode` and `fileno`.

Note: for windows GUI prints, there already proper support, so you can use wsprintf to format unicode strings.

Comment: [link](http://home.netvigator.com/~fhappy/unicode_printf_result.7z). Please see my testing result, I tried u prefix, L prefix, in different function.

Comment: See updated answer. It now works for me. Alpha was created via the character map application.

Comment: My compiler(Pelles C) gave me "error #2048: Undeclared identifier '_O_U16TEXT'." , so could you tell me what value in your fcntl.h is? because I cannot found it in my fcntl.h

Comment: @CLSo `#define _O_U16TEXT 0x20000`

Comment: This answer is for `wchar_t` but not `char16_t` as in the title.

Answer (score 2):

To print/read/open write etc.., you need to convert to 32-bit chars using the `mbsrtowcs` function.

For ALL intents and purposes, char16_t is a multi-byte representation, therefore, one need use `mbr` functions to work with this integral type.

A few answers used the L"prefix" which is completely incorrect. 16-bit strings require the u"prefix".

The following code gets you everything you need to work with 8, 16, and 32-bit string representations.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <uchar.h>
```

You can Google the procedures found in `<wchar.h>` if you don't have manual pages (UNIX).

Gnome.org's GLib has some great code for you to drop-in if overhead isn't an issue.

`char16_t` and `char32_t` are ISO C11 (`iso9899:2011`) extensions.